# CUDA implementation for arbitrary precision arithmetics

Tags: matrix, cuda, matrix-multiplication, arbitrary-precision

I have to multiply two very large (~ 2000 X 2000) dense matrices whose entries are floats with arbitrary precision (I am using GMP and the precision is currently set to 600). I was wondering if there is any CUDA library that supports arbitrary precision arithmetics? The only library that I have found is called CAMPARY however it seems to be missing some references to some of the used functions.

The other solution that I was thinking about was implementing a version of the Karatsuba algorithm for multiplying matrices with arbitrary precision entries. The end step of the algorithm would just be multiplying matrices of doubles, which could be done very efficiently using cuBLAS. Is there any similar implementation already out there?

Comment: [cump](https://github.com/skystar0227/CUMP) may be of interest

Comment: Do you know if cump uses only a basic multiplication algorithm? (At first sight it seems so) It seems that GMP offers considerable speed-up by supplying algorithms with better asymptotic complexity such as the Karatsuba algorithm and FFT based algorithm. I think given the precision that I am using, it might not be worth moving the computation to a GPU unless I use one of these more efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has suggested such a library so far, let's assume that one doesn't exist.

You could always implement the naive implementation:

- One grid thread for each pair of coordinates in the output matrix.
- Each thread performs an inner product of a row and a column in the input matrices.
- Individual element operations will use the code taken from the GMP (hopefully not much more than copy-and-paste).

But you can also do better than this - just like you can do better for regular-float matrix multiplication. Here's my idea (likely not the best of course):

Consider the [worked example](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#shared-memory) of matrix multiplication using shared memory in the [CUDA C Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/). It suggests putting small submatrices in shared memory. You can still do this - but you need to be careful with shared memory sizes (they're small...):

- A typical GPU today has 64 KB shared memory usable per grid block (or more)
- They take 16 x 16 submatrix.
- Times 2 (for the two multiplicands)
- Times ceil(801/8) (assuming the GMP representation uses 600 bits from the mantissa, one bit for the sign and 200 bits from the exponent)
- So 512 * 101 < 64 KB !

That means you can probably just use the code in their worked example as-is, again replacing the float multiplication and addition with code from GMP.

You may then want to consider something like parallelizing the GMP code itself, i.e. using multiple threads to work together on single pairs of 600-bit-precision numbers. That would likely help your shared memory reading pattern. Alternatively, you could interleave the placement of 4-byte sequences from the representation of your elements, in shared memory, for the same effect.

I realize this is a bit hand-wavy, but I'm pretty certain I've waved my hands correctly and it would be a "simple matter of coding".